# how to open tor browser in mac using python?

Tags: python, macos, tor-browser-bundle

I'm trying to open tor browser using mac os in python, but always getting permission denied error, we checked the folder permission and it is there as read and write only

```py
def open_tor():
       # careful about the / when you it's usually \
       subprocess.Popen(["/Applications/Tor Browser.app"],
                     stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                     stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
       time.sleep(10)  # to give plenty of time for Tor to load
```

Error:

```
self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
File 
"/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/subprocess.py", 
line 1845, in _execute_child
raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/Applications/Tor Browser.app'
```

I'm getting permission denied error

Answer (score 0):

> PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied

1. Please make sure the path you call **open** with is a file.
2. Run vscode as **Administrator**.